# Conversion of a delta pair to degree's

Tags: algorithm, geometry, cartesian-product

Undoubtedly this question has been asked before, except I completely lack the knowledge to find it.

I'm trying to write the classic snake (aka Nibbles) game and the logic is pretty straight forward.  Direction is expressed by a delta coordinate pair.  North is -1, 0; east is 0, 1; south is 1,0; and west is 0, -1.

It's been a decade since I took a math course so I'm not exactly sure how to convert those pairs into something where North = 0 degree's; east = 45, south = 90; and west = 135 in which case the problem is drastically simple and becomes a case of clock arithmetic then conversion back to delta pairs.

Also, this is not academic homework but [self-education](https://github.com/devdave/Ping---canvas-helper-library)

Edit:
  Got a working prototype thanks to the selected answer below.
   http://ominian.com/examples/js/pinglib/snakes.html

Comment: If you know you only have 4 directions to go in, why not just have four special cases, and have your direction be expressed by an enum or character or something similar?

Comment: since when was north 0 degrees, east 45 degress etc. Don't you mean 0, 90, 180, 270?

Comment: @David Heffernan Yeah... I was just testing to see if anyone noticed.  As I was walking back inside I realized that mistake.

Comment: glowcoder has the answer. There's no need for trig. Just do it with an enum.

Comment: @glowcoder I'm more interested in a long term solution so in the future I don't start having super large switch statements.

Comment: @David are you meaning a free-form version of the snake game?

Comment: @glowcoder Yes, the current sub-project is to make snake but the final game is going to be a web multi-player version of the old "Red storm rising" game.  I figure there's several more weeks to months of learning on my part to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you really mean degrees then you want increments of 90 degrees rather than 45.
2. You need the `atan2` function (which exists in various forms in many languages). Something like `angle = 180/pi * atan2(dy,dx)` -- the `180/pi` is because `atan2` returns a value in radians. There will be numerous small mismatches between what this does and what you want: `dy` will be taken to increase upwards rather than downwards, 0 will be east rather than north, and `atan2` typically returns values between -pi and +pi rather than between 0 and 2pi. Untangling all these is left as an exercise for the reader :-).
3. If you only need the 4 special cases you described then you could do something ugly and ad hoc. For instance, `angle = 180*(dy-dx>0)+90*(dx!=0)` will do the job because S,W share the property that `dy-dx>0` and E,W share the property that `dx!=0`.
4. You may well find it better to work with `dx,dy` values everywhere and not use angles explicitly at all. For instance, rotation through 90 degrees is just `(dx,dy)=(-dy,dx)` (or `(dy,-dx)` for the other direction).

Comment: For the snake game, #4 seems like the cheapest solution and in retrospect of looking at my notes seems blindly obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

The function you want is atan2() - arctangent of two arguments.  It is there specifically for that purpose.  It returns a result in radians, of course, so you will have to convert to degrees, and it returns a result relative to conventional angles, where zero is along the +X axis, and +pi/2 is along the +Y axis, so you will have to convert to heading angles.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages have an atan2 function which will directly convert x,y deltas into an angle in radians. It's up to you to convert it into degrees.